# gsap split Text on slide

Tags: slide, gsap

I have this part of a slide code, and I want to implement the gsap split Text in h1 (NexText), so that the result is like this: https://codepen.io/GreenSock/pen/aVJRBg

However, I don't know how to implement that in my code.

```
function nextSlide(pageNumber) {
const nextPage = pages[pageNumber];
const currentPage = pages[current];
const nextLeft = nextPage.querySelector(".hero .model-left");
const nextRight = nextPage.querySelector(".hero .model-right");
const currentLeft = currentPage.querySelector(".hero .model-left");
const currentRight = currentPage.querySelector(".hero .model-right");
const nextText = nextPage.querySelector("h1");
const portofolio = document.querySelector(".portofolio");




const tl = new TimelineMax({
  onStart: function() {
    slides.forEach(slide => {
      slide.style.pointerEvents = "none";
    });
  },
  onComplete: function() {
    slides.forEach(slide => {
      slide.style.pointerEvents = "all";
    });
  }
});


tl.fromTo(currentLeft, 0.3, { y: "-10%" }, { y: "-100%" })
  .fromTo(currentRight, 0.3, { y: "10%" }, { y: "100%" }, "-=0.2")
  .to(portofolio, 0.3, { backgroundImage: backgrounds[pageNumber] })
  .fromTo(
    currentPage,
    0.3,
    { opacity: 1, pointerEvents: "all" },
    { opacity: 0, pointerEvents: "none" }
  )
  .fromTo(
    nextPage,
    0.3,
    { opacity: 0, pointerEvents: "none" },
    { opacity: 1, pointerEvents: "all" },
    "-=0.6"
  )
  .fromTo(nextLeft, 0.6, { y: "-100%" }, { y: "-10%" }, "-=0.6")
  .fromTo(nextRight, 0.4, { y: "100%" }, { y: "10%" }, "-=0.8")
  .fromTo(nextText, 0.3, { opacity: 0, y: 0 }, { opacity: 1, y: 0 })
  .set(nextLeft, { clearProps: "all" })
  .set(nextRight, { clearProps: "all" });

current = pageNumber;
}
```

In particular, I don't know how to make these two parts combine:

```
const nextText = nextPage.querySelector ("h1");
```

and

```
var mySplitText = new SplitText ("# quote", {type: "chars, words, lines"})
```

Comment: This has been answered [on the GreenSock forums](https://greensock.com/forums/topic/22639-splittext-implementation/?tab=comments#comment-106976)

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve can be done via:

```
var variableThatStoresMySplit H1= new SplitText (nextText , {type: "chars"})
```

And then later in your code you have to use a stagger to through the array SplitText created for you by doing:

```
gsap.staggerFrom(variableThatStoresMySplit .chars, 0.5, {y:20, opacity:0}, 0.04)
```

I hope this solves your issue

Comment: It worked for me. Currently this is my slide:
https://codepen.io/df4fgg/pen/GRgLZom

However, I tried to combine my slide and the effect with a free alternative to the greensock splitText plugin (splitting.js):

https://codepen.io/df4fgg/pen/OJPeXbZ

But I can't combine splitting with my slide.